# Completar formulario con datos de JSON - EasyAutocomplete

Tags: javascript, json, autocompletar

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un buscador con `EasyAutocomplete` hasta ahora logre realizar la búsqueda y me retorna un `JSON` con los datos de la persona que lo busco por documento de identidad.
La duda es: como agrego esos datos del `JSON` en los campos del formulario.

así esta el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi .js

```
$("#autocomplete-search").easyAutocomplete({
     url: function(search) {
         return "{{route('buscar.persona')}}?search=" + search;
     },

     getValue: "nro_doc"
```

y el json de la búsqueda

```
1: {id: 3, nombre: "Pedro", apellidos: "Dominguez Sabat", motivo_viaje: "Trabajo", procedencia: "namekusei", nro_doc:"48810254",…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que escuchar el evento `onChooseEvent`, entonces cuando el usuario selecciona un elemento de `easyAutocomplete` este evento se lanza y tu solo tienes que asignar los `values` a los campos que necesites.

Aqui tienes un ejemplo.

```
$("#autocomplete-search").easyAutocomplete({
        url: function (search) {
            return "{{route('buscar.persona')}}?search=" + search;
        },
        getValue: "nro_doc",
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function () {
                var nombres = $("#autocomplete-search").getSelectedItemData().nombre;
                var apellidos = $("#autocomplete-search").getSelectedItemData().apellidos;
                $("#nombres").val(nombres);
                $("#apellidos").val(apellidos);
            },
        }
    });
```